# Why is Owl Carousel Displaying 3 images at once

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I have specified in the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 300,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true
    });
});
```

However, it still shows 3 items at one time. I do not want this! I only want to see 1 item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 300,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        items:1,
        singleItem: true
    });
});
```